# Javascript get image src: FF shows escaped chars, IE doesn't

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, escaping

If I set:

```
<img src="test-àè" onclick="alert(this.src);">
```

on FF the alert shows an escaped message: `test-%C3%A0`
while on IE it shows the unescaped version: `test-àè`

I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

in my page and windows-1252 encoding

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
```

Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: The SRC you've provided isn't a valid URI and isn't legal. You should escape it according to the rules of RFC2396/RFC3986 before putting it in your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because firefox (and Chrome too) automatically URL encodes your the src because it is assumed to be a URL.

Here's a little test:

`<img src="test-àè" foo='test-àè' onclick="alert(this.src);alert(this.getAttribute('foo'));">`

In ie you get 'test-àè' 2 times.  In Firefox you get 'test-àè' only the second time.